# Seeking Equivalent Microsoft Graph Command for AzureAD Integrated Applications

Tags: powershell, graph, command-line, azure-active-directory

I'm currently transitioning from using the AzureAD PowerShell module to the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK for managing Azure resources. I've encountered a specific use case where I'm not able to find an equivalent command in the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK.

In the AzureAD module, I use the following command to list all service principals that are tagged as integrated applications with Azure AD:
`Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All:$true | Where-Object {$_.Tags -eq "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"}`

This command helps me identify Azure AD integrated applications, specifically tagged as "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp". I'm looking for an equivalent or workaround in the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK to retrieve the same information. Any suggestions or commands in the Graph SDK for this purpose?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran below Azure AD commands to list all service principals that are tagged as integrated applications, I got **response** like this:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All:$true | Where-Object {$_.Tags -eq "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"}
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can make use of below **equivalent** Microsoft Graph PowerShell command to retrieve the same information:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications
Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "tags/any(tag:tag eq 'WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp')"
```

**Response:**

[image]